# SSRS expression reuslt not formatting as number when exported to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've tried just about everything I've found on here but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong so I don't know if the reason lies in my expression. I am pretty new to this stuff so not sure if it's obvious.

Here is my expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!Duration.Value > 0, Floor(Fields!Duration.Value / 3600) & ":" & Format(CDate(DateAdd("s", Fields!Duration.Value, "00:00")), "mm:ss"), IIF(Fields!LastTime.Value = Fields!FirstTime.Value, "Passing by", "Still Occupied"))
```

It takes 2 columns' cells (`FirstTime` and `LastTime`), calculates the difference between the two and puts it into an h:mm:ss format. If `FirstTime` and `LastTime` match, it will put "Passing by" instead. Otherwise it will put "Still Occupied".

All is fine but if the report is exported to Excel, the column cannot be totaled or calculated in any way and I can't even format the column as numbers to do it.

Any ideas on why this could be happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot add the values is that you are converting them to a text field that looks like a time value.

Instead of converting your seconds to mm:ss, you should add the seconds to a date and then display it in the mm:ss format.

If you want to be able to add the times in Excel, you'd need to format the text box with the FORMAT Property of **mm:ss** instead of using the format function.

```
=IIF(Fields!Duration.Value > 0, DATEADD("s", Fields!Duration.Value, CDATE("1899-12-31")), 
 IIF(Fields!LastTime.Value = Fields!FirstTime.Value, "Passing by", "Still Occupied"))
```

12/31/1899 is day 0 of windows dates so you can add times together without adding days in the SUM and Average of the Excel Status bar. Note how Excel doesn't show the date in the Formula Bar.

[image]

Comment: I had a feeling the Format had something to do with it. It is partially working, however, now if the time is over 1 day, the hours go to 0. (ex. if the total time is 25 h 31 m 50 s, it shows as 01:31:50) This is one of the issues I had before formatting. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: The Excel format that lets you have more than 24 hours is `[h]:mm:ss` but I haven't been able to figure out how to export that format from SSRS. Of course you can change the format in Excel afterwards but that's not ideal.